# How to select rows in an R data frame based on values of previous rows

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have what seems to be a simple problem which I haven't been able to solve.  I have an R data frame which consists of a single column of data points, as show below.  I would like to subset into a new data frame which contains data points based on value of previous data points.

So below, I would for example like to subset all the rows where the previous value was greater than .04.  Any ideas would be appreciated.  Thank you.

```
         Price
[1,] -0.006666667
[2,]  0.040268456
[3,]  0.051612903
[4,] -0.006134969
[5,]  0.006172840
[6,]  0.006134969
[7,]  0.030487805
```

Comment: There's a problem here. That's not a dataframe, or at least that's not how `print.data.frame` displays one. It appears to be an R matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
x[c(FALSE, head(x$Price, -1) > 0.04), , drop = FALSE]
```

(From your print, it seems your object might be a matrix, not a data.frame. If it is the case, replace `x$Price` with `x[, "Price"]`.)

Comment: Suggestion: use `, drop=FALSE` to avoid losing the data.frame structure.

Answer (score 2):

These types of manipulations can be done in a way which directly mimics our thought process by using a time series representation.  This also has the advantage that its now in such a representation and that will facilitate further computations as well.  Suppose `DF` is the data frame.  Convert it to a [zoo](http://cran.r-project.org/package=zoo) object `z` and then extract those components of `z` whose lag exceeds `0.04` :

```
> library(zoo)
> z <- zoo(DF$Price)
> z[lag(z, -1) > 0.04]
           3            4 
 0.051612903 -0.006134969
```

If `result` is the value of the last line of code then `time(result)` gives the times (`3` and `4` in the above example) and `coredata(result)` gives the data values.