# Referring to previous row in R apply

Tags: r

Is there a way to refer to the previous row in `apply`'s in R?

For example, my `data.frame` is sorted in the order of dates, and I want to find the differences between the date in the previous row and current row. This is easy in a loop.

```
for( i in 2:nrow(Y)) {
      Y[i,]$window =  as.numeric(as.Date( Y[i, ]$start_date )  -  
                         as.Date( Y[i-1, ]$end_date ))
}
```

Can I do this using apply?

Comment: I wouldn't use `apply`, I'd use a simple vectorized form: `Y$window =  c(NA, as.numeric(as.Date( tail(Y$start_date,-1) )  -  
                         as.numeric(as.Date( head(Y$end_date,-1) )))`

Comment: what is the code meant to do in the `i = 1` case?

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft -- snap. (does an answer trump a comment)

Comment: @mnel -- shame on you :-)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776925/how-to-select-rows-in-an-r-data-frame-based-on-values-of-previous-rows

Answer (score 1):

Try using `head` (or `tail`)

```
Y$window <- as.numeric(c(NA, as.Date(tail(y$start.date,-1)) - as.Date(head(y$end.date,-1)) ))
```